# JAX-RS @PathParam beginning with variable argument

Tags: rest, jax-rs

I am using JAX-RS 1.x to develop a simple RESTFul service like /{app_id}/job/list/

So I have defined a resource class like below:

```
@Path("/{app_id}/job")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JobService {

  @GET
  @Path("list")
  public Response list(@PathParam("app_id") final String appId) {
    // ....
  }
}
```

But it seems the implementation (RestEasy in my case) is not able to find this resource. If I make it `/job/{app_id}/list`, it works but not `/{app_id}/job/list`.

Is it because I have used variable `{app_id}` as a beginning path element? Does JAX-RS expects first path element to be fixed?

The root resource is defined as just `/`.

Comment: Do you have another class with a URI path template such as @Path("/") ?

Comment: Yes, I do have one root resource class mapped as @Path("/"). This is to route all request like `http://host/webapp-context/` to this default class. But the problem is with resources mapped as `http://host/webapp-context/{app_id}/job/list`.

Comment: Thanks Paulino, removing resource class with `@Path("/")` actually solved my problem. Can you please explain why having class with just `@path("/")` breaks other resource class in this scenario?

Comment: Personally, I don't have a solid explanation; I'll have to research more. What I think is that having one class with a URI path template such as @Path("/") will make it a root resource class. JAX RS will look for @Path("/{app_id}/job") in your root resource class methods because the /{app_id} matches the full URI template for that root class given that {app_id} is a variable. You can implement @Path("/{app_id}/job") as a method in your "/" root resource class.

Comment: Thanks Paulino for the explanation, I am almost sure this was the case  in my code. I didn't realise having a root class with just `@Path("/")` can actually create ambiguity. Thanks again, this solves my problem :)

Comment: Sure! Please don't forget to upvote my comments please :)

Comment: I wish I could up-vote. But my current reputation doesn't allow that :(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it because I have used variable {app_id} as a beginning path element? Does JAX-RS expects first path element to be fixed?

No, a template parameter can be anywhere in the path and it can be on the resource (= class) or subresource (= method).

Your code works if there is no other JAX-RS resource. Check your system for other `@Path`s that might match your URI path.

Comment: Thanks Tichodroma for clarifying my doubt, I will check if there is any ambiguity in @Path across application. The implementation is throwing javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException.

Comment: Tichodroma, you were correct, I was having ambiguous `@Path` in a subtle way, that Paulino pointed out correctly without looking at my code.

Comment: And Thanks Tichodroma for fixing formatting as well. I will take care of this in future.